# issue with `for` loop, causes game to crash when button to run loop is clicked

Tags: javascript

in trying to get a few numbers (var belief and trinkets) to go up per second (using `for` loop), i run into the error "expected a conditional expression but instead saw an assignment" when using the analyse function over the following piece of code:

```
function trinketCount(number) {
    if(towers >= 1) {
        var trinketCap = 500;
        for(; trinkets = trinketCap;) {
            trinkets = trinkets + (towers * 2);
        }
        document.getElementById('trinkets').innerHTML = trinkets;
    }
}
```

and also in the following, very similar, loop:

```
function beliefCount(number) {
    if(towers >= 1) {
        var beliefCap = 600;
        for(; belief = beliefCap;) {
            belief = belief + towers;
            document.getElementById('belief').innerHTML = belief;
        }
    }
}
```

clicking the button to build a 'tower' also causes the whole thing to crash.
i am fairly new to js so i apologise if the problem is obvious! also check it out for yourself at https://codepen.io/dirtbf/project/full/XjvdMX

Comment: Yet another case of `=` vs `==(=)`?

Comment: in case you still dont know, @raina77ow is referring to `for(; trinkets = trinketCap;)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"expected a conditional expression but instead saw an assignment"`

This is exactly the problem.

`for(; trinkets = trinketCap;) {`

`for(; belief = beliefCap;) {`

You're assigning the values in here instead of checking whether they equal each other. Did that error come with a line number?

Fixed function versions:

```
function trinketCount(number) {
    if(towers >= 1) {
        var trinketCap = 500;
        for(; trinkets == trinketCap;) {
            trinkets = trinkets + (towers * 2);
        }
        document.getElementById('trinkets').innerHTML = trinkets;
    }
}

function beliefCount(number) {
    if(towers >= 1) {
        var beliefCap == 600;
        for(; belief = beliefCap;) {
            belief = belief + towers;
            document.getElementById('belief').innerHTML = belief;
        }
    }
}
```